# Individual Kendo UI widget css

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

Is it possible to get the css that targets each individual Kendo UI widget separately?

I'm trying to style a dropdown widget but I don't want to wade through lots of css just to copy out the bits that I need.

I had a look at the theme builder thinking that it would let me do this but that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to style all Kendo Dropdowns? 
All Kendo Dropdowns are wrapped in a span that have the class .k-dropdown on them. This is how a typical Dropdown is structured.

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="size_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="size_option_selected">
  <span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-input">S - 6 3/4"</span>
    <span unselectable="on" class="k-select">
        <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s">select</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <select id="size" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;">
    <option value="S - 6 3/4&quot;" selected="selected">S - 6 3/4"</option>
    <option value="M - 7 1/4&quot;">M - 7 1/4"</option>
    <option value="L - 7 1/8&quot;">L - 7 1/8"</option>
    <option value="XL - 7 5/8&quot;">XL - 7 5/8"</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Comment: That's what I'm trying to do at the moment - it will probably extend to a few other controls in the future. I don't want to have to either pluck out the css i need from the official file or have to override lots of selectors. I was hoping the css for each control would be available in individual chunks.

Comment: If you can't do it with the theme builder then the CSS 'span.k-dropdown' is your best bet. If you need to select the dropdown it self then you can use 'span.k-dropdown select'